# Should session id be encrypted in cookie?

Tags: security, jwt, session-cookies

In a single page app:

I want to use an httpOnly/Secure cookie to verify that a Bearer token has not been stolen from Local Storage.

In other words, the cookie and the bearer token must be presented and cross checked before being considered valid.

For example:

User logs in successfully with Username/Password.

A Jwt Bearer token is created and includes a session Id of 12345.

Also, a cookie is formatted as jwt and signed and contains a claim of the session Id of 12345.

Now when an ajax request is made with the token and cookie, the session id is compared.  If they match, then the request is fulfilled.

Is this secure? Or should the Session Id be encrypted on the cookie or token?

Comment: "Secure" is not a boolean value.

Comment: @Flimzy, I am not quite following you.  Is there a better way to word the question?

Comment: Nothing is either "secure" or "insecure." It's not a boolean value. Something is secure to a certain degree, and for a certain attack vector.

Comment: If you can afford having the token in an httpOnly cookie, why do you need it in localStorage?

Comment: Because the single page app needs the info in the token to operate. It can't read an httpOnly cookie. By having both, the app gets the data, but the httpOnly cookie confirms that it is valid.

Comment: If you have your backend (api) on the same server where you downloaded the spa from, the cookie is enough, the spa does not need access to the token, the cookie will be sent automatically. If the backend is a different origin (another domain), then you can't check the token anyway, because the cookie will not be sent. The only usual reason to have access to the token besides sending it to different apis is to read its expiry, but you can solve that differently. If there is more info in the token, that can also be read from the api.

Comment: It's true the same data that is in the bearer token could be put into the cookie and then that is used by the server instead of the bearer token.  But the bearer token is a convenient way to get that data from the server and store it on the client. Further, I think it is more secure two have two items which would have to be stolen and used together to launch an attack. The two are validated against each other on the server using a type, and a sessionId. (See below discussion)

Comment: The client is also supplied with a refresh token for when the bearer token expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've told us, your setup might be secure, or it might not be.  You would need to provide more details to let us know for sure.

For example, based on what you've told us, you're basically issuing the user two distinct bearer tokens saying that "the bearer of this token is allowed to access session 12345", one of the tokens being stored in an `httpOnly` cookie and the other in LocalStorage, and only allowing access if both tokens are present and valid and if they match each other.

However, your description doesn't make it clear whether a LocalStorage token would also be valid as a cookie token, or vice versa.  If they could be, an attacker who captured one of the tokens could simply submit the same captured token twice in the same Ajax request, once in the cookie and once in the request parameters, and therefore appear valid.

Furthermore, simply checking that the two tokens in a request aren't the same may not be sufficient, since an attacker might be able to capture e.g. two distinct valid LocalStorage tokens for the same session.  Rather, what you need to do to prevent attacks like this is to include some kind of a *token type identifier* in the signed data that makes up the token (e.g. just `type: "cookie"` vs. `type: "param"`) and to verify that the type of each token actually matches the manner in which they're presented to the server.

Or, alternatively, you could use two different signing keys for the cookie tokens and the parameter tokens; this way, copying a token from LocalStorage into a cookie or vice versa would automatically render the signature invalid.

That said, as long as you somehow ensure that each type of token is valid only when presented via the appropriate channel, your setup is at least *no less* secure than simply using a single token.  It should also protect against certain types of additional attacks, such as CSRF attacks (which can allow an attacker to make malicious requests with the legitimate user's cookies) and certain kinds of JS injection attacks (which might compromise the user's LocalStorage, but not their cookies).

However, we can't really tell whether these attacks are relevant threats for your application, and whether or not there may be other attacks that your scheme is *not* sufficient to protect against.  In particular, while your scheme should be sufficient protection against attacks that *only* compromise LocalStorage, it's worth noting that most kinds of attacks that can do that also allow the attacker to do other things, such as making their own Ajax requests from within the user's browser (which would thwart your scheme).

That said, at least your scheme (if implemented correctly) provides CSRF protection, which is a useful thing.  Whether it provides anything more than that is another matter.

(In any case, generally there's no need to encrypt the session ID, or any token containing it, as long as the attacker cannot do anything malicious just by knowing the session ID.  And if they could, then having a session ID like "12345" would be a bad idea anyway, since it would be easy for an attacker to try all session IDs from, say, 0 to 999999.)

Comment: thank you so much.  Very helpful.  Yes, I will include a type identifier. And thank you for the note on the encryption.  In my case, I think there is no need.  And also good point that the attacker could still make an Ajax request from within the user's browser.  I had not thought of that angle before and will give it some consideration.